# Problems with installing grub?

Tags: grub2

It is a dual boot with windows 8. the link is paste.ubuntu.com/6385594 I have two hard drives. My C:has my windows and D: is designated to ubuntu. I have to use my usb drive in order to get grub. Boot-repair tells me to make a disk. I am not sure what to do with the disk once I have made it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6385594/

You only have one hard drive. Do not confuse Windows use of partitions as drives.

You need to use a 64 bit version of Boot-Repair to correctly fix your system. It looks like you tried to install wubi inside Windows. Wubi does not work with gpt partitioned drives or any pre-installed Windows 8.

You have installed in BIOS boot mode, but Windows is in UEFI boot mode. Best if Ubuntu also is in UEFI boot mode.

You also need to turn off fast boot or the always on hibernation that Windows 8 uses.

Follow install instructions in these links and install a 64 bit version:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Comment: I have seen both of those numerous times, I have reinstalled 3x. I have used different types of ways to write to the usb. Is there a way I can use boot-repair 64 bit? I would rather not install again if I do not need to......